# Blog Gem/Engine for Rails/Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mongoid, blogs, rails-engines

What Rails blogging gem/engines are there that can be used with MongoDB/Mongoid?

I've used Typo and RefineryCMS-Blog for MySQL/ActiveRecord apps, but they don't work with Mongoid (and frankly are more heavyweight than I need).

Answer (score 2):

You'll definitely want to checkout locomotive

http://locomotivecms.com/

https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine

Answer (score 0):

I used refinery before so didn't use this time because it's complicated and too big for my app. I was about to create mongoid branch for blogit gem but found bloggy. 
I don't know if you need authenticated user access to your blog but you shouldn't anyway so
I used [bloggy](https://github.com/zbruhnke/bloggy) gem to integrate jerkyll blog which is databaseless.

Jekyll is the most popular blog system out there and whats nice about bloggy gem is that you don't have to make configurations, it just places your blog into "/blog" path.
Another plus is that http://jekyllthemes.org has many themes you can choose from.

Note that -for me- it gets stuck sometimes but I find that it does create the necessary files even it gets stuck. 
Be sure that after you create a post remove the "published: false" from the markdown before generating it.